# Parsing key:value metadata in a file

Tags: parsing, lexical-analysis, lex, yacc

I have written some Flex and Bison code for parsing a file.

The following is a simplified example of the input file as well as the code used for parsing.

There are a few things I am not satisfied with:

- The way keywords are recognized (Marked with [1] in tokenizer.lex), because the rules also recognize the following whitespaces, which are not part of the keyword itself.
- The part after the colon (:) is quite unflexible. If there is a whitespace at the beginning, it is always recognized as `STRING`.

There has been a nicer solution before, but that one couldn't handle spaces in the right hand side string.

I am mostly interested in the issues I mentioned above but I'm open to any suggestions, as this is a completely new topic to me.

**example.txt**

```
File                  :TheFileName.txt
Value                 :19
Date                  :17.08.16
Description           :This is a description
```

**grammar.y**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int yylex();
int yyparse();
FILE *yyin;
extern int line_num;

void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%union {
        int ival;
        float fval;
        char *sval;
        char cval;
}

%token NEWLINE

%token PARAM_FILE
%token PARAM_DESCRIPTION 
%token PARAM_DATE
%token PARAM_VALUE

%token <ival> INTEGER
%token <fval> FLOAT
%token <sval> STRING
%token <sval> DATE

%%

File: AssignList;

AssignList: Assign
          | Assign NEWLINES
          | Assign NEWLINES AssignList
          ;

Assign: PARAM_FILE        ':' STRING  {printf("Found 'File': [%s]\n", $3);}
      | PARAM_DESCRIPTION ':' STRING  {printf("Found 'Description': [%s]\n", $3);}
      | PARAM_DATE        ':' DATE    {printf("Found 'Date': [%s]\n", $3);}
      | PARAM_VALUE       ':' INTEGER {printf("Found 'Value': [%d]\n", $3);}
      ;

NEWLINES: NEWLINES NEWLINE
        | NEWLINE
        ;

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    yydebug = 0;
    do {
            yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));

    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
        printf("Error parsing file! Error on line %d,  Message: %s\n", line_num, s);
}
```

**tokenizer.lex**

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include "grammar.tab.h"

int line_num = 1;
%}

char    [^:\n]
digit   [0-9]
digit1  [1-9]
integer {digit1}{digit}*
float   (integer|0)("."|,){digit}+

date    {digit}{2}"."{digit}{2}"."{digit}{2}
string  {char}+

%%
    /* [1] I don't like this solution */
File[ \t]*          { return PARAM_FILE; }
Description[ \t]*   { return PARAM_DESCRIPTION; }
Date[ \t]*          { return PARAM_DATE; }
Value[ \t]*         { return PARAM_VALUE; }

:                   { return ':'; }

{integer} { yylval.ival = atoi(yytext);   return INTEGER; }
{float}   { yylval.fval = atof(yytext);   return FLOAT; }
{date}    { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return DATE; }

[ \t] ;
\n { line_num++; return NEWLINE; }     /* count the line numbers */

{string}  { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return STRING; }

%%
/* Empty 3rd section */
```

**Makefile**

```
grammar.tab.c: grammar.y
    bison -d grammar.y

grammar.tab.h: grammar.y
    bison -d grammar.y

lex.yy.c: tokenizer.lex
    flex.exe tokenizer.lex

parser.exe: lex.yy.c grammar.tab.c grammar.tab.h
    gcc -DYYDEBUG=1 lex.yy.c grammar.tab.c -o parser.exe

run: parser.exe 
    type example.txt | parser.exe
```

**output of `type example.txt | parser.exe`**

```
Found 'File': [TheFileName.txt]
Found 'Value': [19]
Found 'Date': [17.08.16]
Found 'Description': [This is a description]
```

Comment: This: "the rules recognize more than necessary" suggests that your code doesn't do what it is intended to do and that you seek a solution for this. Beware that this makes it off-topic here.

Comment: @BCdotWEB it does what it is intended  to do. I finally came up with that solution, that works but doesn't satisfy me. I have a solution, but I am searching for a better one, this is what reviews are good for, aren't they? If this is off-topic, I am very sorry, but I don't think it is.

Comment: @BCdotWEB by "more than necessary"  I mean that I had to add whitespaces after the keywords. I think there is neater way to handle that an that the more experienced folks can tell me how I can improve my code, so that I am able to learn.